# Why can't a full stop be used to end titles and section headings?

Tags: titles, periods, heading

According to many official sources a full stop should not be used to end titles [1, 2]. But they never mention why. Other questionable sources mention using a full stop to end a title lowers reading comprehension [3]. I for one do not like arbitrary rules. Moreover, titles are sentence, and I find them aesthetically [4] and grammatically uncomfortable to look at without a full stop. So, could someone shed light on this matter?

1. “and it should not have a full stop at the end”;
   https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/essaysandletters/titlesandheadings
2. “Don’t use a full stop to end headings”;
   https://www.stylemanual.gov.au/structuring-content/headings
3. https://www.editage.com/insights/omit-colons-and-full-stops-after-headings-in-research-papers, https://cuttingedgepr.com/articles/does-a-headline-need-a-full-stop-or-period/
4. Punctuation in Design: Design Implication of Full Stop in Headers;
   https://blog.prototypr.io/full-stop-in-headers-9a991c0f79df

Comment: In "Moby Dick" (from Project Gutenberg), chapter headings end with a full stop. Note also that most headings and titles are not sentences.

Comment: Very few titles are sentences, they're phrases, words, etc (exceptions might be "See Spot Run", "I Know What You Did Last Summer"). Some style guides say not to end with a full stop because it's good to be consistent, but there's no profound reason other than it's more usual to not have them, and some titles do have them. And full stops aren't used after other labels such as street signs, signs for shops, labels on food and clothes, etc. This also is not unique to English - not sure of any language that  does it routinely.

Comment: You say *I for one do not like arbitrary rules.* - There are few, if any, "rules" in English - there is only guidance. Feel free not to follow the guidance - many great writers did not follow guidance. Do you wish for there to be an arbitrary rule that compels the use of full-stops in titles? Of interest: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416059/history-of-periods-in-ads-headlines.

Comment: Inverting your question, *what purpose would a full stop serve at the end of a title?* it's obvious that you've reached the end of the title from the change in font/size, so you don't need it as a marker of the end of a sentence - even if your title is a sentence. It's just a pointless little dot that messes up the centring if your title is centred

Comment: Are you writing your titles in sentence case or in title case? In any case, as @ChrisH said, the full stop is a separator — one that is not needed, as the title is already set apart.

Comment: << Eats Shoots & Leaves >> even has a semicomma on the dust jacket. // Below sentence level, punctuation 'rules' are even looser.

Comment: A period after a longer phrase or clause may cause the reader to think they have (mis)read a complete sentence, making them unnecessarily stumble/reread.

Comment: The title of the 2022 documentary [Sr.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21816824/) ends in a period (it's about the life of Robert Downey, Sr.)

Answer (score 1):

Given the usual purpose of the modern-era full stop, that is, to end a sentence as an aid to the reader, such punctuation was not needed when titles began to appear on their very own page in a larger font and gave a terse name for the text. In early printing, titles often provided a summary of the topics addressed by the text and could contain multiple clauses.  The more text you have, the more you need to demarcate sentence and clause boundaries.